# PostgreSQL add constant time to date function: now()::date

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-date-functions

They moved us from MySQL to PostgreSQL.  I'm trying to re-write a query to get data between two dates.  There are no variables in PSQL so I'm trying to get the data with the 'now()::date' function but I can't figure out how to add the time.

The date can always change, depends on the current date so 'now()::date' is perfect.  The time however is constant, it's always from 19:00:00 to 19:34:59.

I tried writing it like this:

```
between (now()::date + ' 19:00:00') and (now()::date-1 + ' 19:34:59')
```

and several more variations but it doesn't work.

Can anybody please guide me in the right direction?

Thank you all very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a `time` to a `date`

```
between current_date + time '19:00:00' and current_date + time '19:34:59'
```

Or if the upper limit should be "tomorrow" just add one day to `current_date`

```
between current_date + time '19:00:00' and (current_date + 1) + time '19:34:59'
```